# Atualizar página se der certo

Tags: php, javascript

Esse é meu código php:

```
if(isset($_POST['menu'])){


$menu               = $_POST['menu'];
$dateFoundation     = $_POST['date'];
$cnpj               = $_POST['cnpj'];
$latitude           = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude          = $_POST['longitude'];
$link               = $_POST['link'];
$site               = $_POST['site'];
$facebook           = $_POST['facebook'];
$instagram          = $_POST['instagram'];
$googleplus         = $_POST['googleplus'];
$pinterest          = $_POST['pinterest'];


$stmtUpdateMoreInfo = $conn->prepare("SELECT menu.fundation_date, menu.cnpj, menu.link, address.lat, address.lng
                                     FROM menu
                                     LEFT JOIN public.address ON menu.address_id = address.address_id
                                     WHERE menu_id = :menu");

$stmtUpdateMoreInfo->bindValue(":menu", $menu);
$stmtUpdateMoreInfo->execute();
$informations = $stmtUpdateMoreInfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


echo'to aquii no php';


if ($informations->fundation_date !== $dateFoundation) {

    $newDate = ($informations->fundation_date !== $dateFoundation) ? correctBadWords($dateFoundation) : $informations->fundation_date;
    echo'variável do banco de dados? '.$informations->fundation_date;
    echo'variável nova '.$newDate;
}


if ($informations->cnpj !== $cnpj) {

    $newCnpj = ($informations->cnpj !== $cnpj) ? correctBadWords($cnpj) : $informations->cnpj;
    echo'cnpj que está no banco de dados?  '.$informations->cnpj;
    echo'cnpj novo?  '.$cnpj;

}

if ($informations->fundation_date !== $dateFoundation || $informations->cnpj !== $cnpj) {
    $stmtUpdateInformations = $conn->prepare("UPDATE menu SET fundation_date = :date, cnpj = :cnpj WHERE menu_id = :menu");
    $stmtUpdateInformations->bindValue(":date", $newDate);
    $stmtUpdateInformations->bindValue(":cnpj", $newCnpj);
    $stmtUpdateInformations->bindValue(":menu", $menu);

    if($stmtUpdateInformations->execute()){
        echo 'true';
    }else{
        echo'false';
    }
}
```

Esse meu javascript:

```
 if (moreInformations) {
       $.ajax({
        url: './model/functions/more_informations.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {date: $("#date-foundation").val(), cnpj: $("#cnpj").val(),
        latitude: $("#latitude").val(), longitude: $("#longitude").val(),
        link: $("#link").val(), site: $("#site").val(), facebook: $("#facebook").val(),
        instagram: $("#instagram").val(), googleplus: $("#googleplus").val(), pinterest: $("#pinterest").val(),
        menu: $("#menuid").val()},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('to aqui'+data);
            if(data === 'true'){
                location.reload(true);
            }else{
                alert('deu pau');
            }
        }
    });
    }

});
```

Como faço pra quando executar meu comando do banco, a página recarregue? O que devo colocar no retorno do ajax? E tenho mais uma dúvida, no meu arquivo php, quando uma das coisas alterarem ou a data ou o cnpj eu entro no comando e atualizo, se não alterar nada não faz nada, e se alterar um o outro permanece igual. Como fazer o outro permanecer o mesmo? Ele pega e está deixando null quando atualiza um e nao atualiza o outro.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você escreve

```
echo'to aquii no php';
```

Você retorna uma página para o usuário, o que o `$.ajax` reconhece como sucesso - ou seja, qualquer coisa que você escrever vai contar como sucesso. Você só pode dar `echo` em alguma coisa depois que a transação com o banco de dados estiver completa.

Para informar o browser se houve sucesso ou erro, utilize

```
http_response_code(501) //erro interno ou 
http_response_code(200) //sucesso
```

Sobre os outros campos, você pode incluir o atributo `required` no html para forçar que valores vazios sejam enviados - é uma proteção superficial, pois ainda será possível enviar valores nulos via js. A validação desses valores também deve ser feita no servidor antes de inserir no banco de dados.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php 

echo '<script>location.reload();</script>';

?>
```